# possible to user per service interceptors?

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

Is it possible to override my authInterceptor on a per service basis?

**What I'm trying to accomplish:**

I'm using a JWT for my own api, but occasionally I'm using Google Apis and need to reset my Authorization header to my google auth token rather than my local auth token.  Here's what I have so far.  It sets my authorization header sitewide using my own api token.  So how do I override this if I were to make a GoogleService?

```
services.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $window, $log, localStorageService) {
return {
    request: function (config) {

        config.headers = config.headers || {};
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer '+localStorageService.get('token');
        return config;
    },
    response: function (response) {
        return response || $q.when(response);
    }
};
});

services.config(function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
});
```

Comment: Yes, you can use one interceptor per service, however, the interceptor will need to look at the url being requested to see if it is a request it should interact with.

Comment: so am I better off to just use this one authInterceptor throughout my site and uses a regex in request method that determines what header to set?